# Acumulate delayed data and trigger them after 5 minutes

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Google Dataflow job that reads data from PubSub, aggregates de data and in the end, sends the data to an InflluxDB. What I want to achieve is to aggregate the data in windows of 1 minute but to have only an entry in the DB for each minute. The problem is that I want to allow lateness data so I need to accumulate the data during a period of 5 minutes and then to send to the DB a unique entry.

Is it possible? I tried to do that with the below code, but I don't get what I want:

```java
input.apply(Window
  .<KV<String, String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
  .triggering(
      AfterProcessingTime
        .pastFirstElementInPane()
        .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
  .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
  .discardingFiredPanes()
```

Answer (score 1):

I already collaborated on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55954482/apache-beam-windowing-consider-late-data-but-emit-only-one-pane/55955425). You can use `.triggering(Never.ever())` to omit sending the `ON TIME` panes. Then, as you are already doing, set the allowed lateness to 5 minutes for late records.

It's also important to change the [`Window.ClosingBehavior`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.ClosingBehavior.html) to `FIRE_ALWAYS`. This way we account for the case where there is no late data but we haven't emitted the on-time records. Once the window is closed it will always emit a final pane with [`PaneInfo.isLast`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.html#isLast--) set to true.

So, for your case, the code would be something like:

```java
input.apply(Window
  .<KV<String, String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
  .triggering(Never.ever())
  .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(5), Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS)
  .discardingFiredPanes()
```